# What can cause an onSubmit="return checkTheForm()" not being executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I know I know; there's [a](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/formvalidation.html) [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134733/html-javascript-simple-form-validation-on-submit) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-javascript) [posts](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.nl/2013/02/jquery-test-check-if-checkbox-checked.html) on the internet about this. I know I need to use `<form action="index.html" onSubmit="return checkTheForm()">` But I just don't understand why the code I wrote doesn't seem to work.

In my HTML I've got the following:

```
<form method="post" action="/index" onsubmit="return validateBuyForm();">
    <input id="agreeToTerms" name="agreeToTerms" type="checkbox" /> I agree<br />
    <input value="Buy that stuff!!" id="pay" type="submit" />
</form>
```

and in my js I've got this:

```
function validateBuyForm() {
    alert('we are validating!!');
    return false;
}
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zx2rx/

My problem is that I never see the alert, even though I think I'm following all the tutorials on the internet. Does anybody have the winning tip on what I'm doing wrong here?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: check this one http://jsbin.com/feyut/1/edit

Comment: Don't wrap code in onload method in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zx2rx/3/ Otherwise, `validateBuyForm()` is not on global scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That problem is just a JsFiddle problem. Functions declared in JsFiddle are automatically wrapped in their own scope, so they are not global and therefore not visible to the code declared in your `onsubmit` attribute. If you force the function to be global it will work:

```
window.validateBuyForm = function() {
    alert('we are validating!!');
    return false;
}
```

[Update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zx2rx/4/)