# javascript: validate form before submit?

Tags: javascript, forms

I would really appreciate anyone's help with this as I just can't seem to get it working. I am using a javascript code to check my form before it is submitted. I check for things like empty boxes.

If boxes are empty then this should display one of three divs which contains a standard error text.

"There was an error"

I have three different divs, div1 div2 and div3 which contain error statements. I have done this because I have divided my form into three sections. Therefore I want my javascript to perform three different checks on the three different sections in my form and if an error has occurred in which ever section then display div1 or div 2 or div3 for that section.

```
Section 1 
<div 1>
<input = firstname>
<input = lastname>
<input = email>
<input = email2>

section 2
<div 2>
<input = contactnum>
<input = mobnum>
<input = postcode>

section 3
<div 3>
<input = compname>
<input = compreg>
```

here is my javascript code I am trying to put together but it's not working, it submits the form without doing any checks. please can someone show me where I am going wrong.

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var a = document.forms["register"]["firstname"].value;
        var b = document.forms["register"]["lastname"].value;
        var c = document.forms["register"]["email"].value;
        var d = document.forms["register"]["email2"].value;
        if (a == null || a == "" || b == null || b == "" || c == null || c == ""|| d == null || d == "") {
            $(".form_error").show();
            $('html,body').animate({
               scrollTop: $(".form_error").offset().top - 180 
            });


            var e = document.forms["register"]["contactnum"].value;
            var f = document.forms["register"]["mobnum"].value;
            var g = document.forms["register"]["postcode"].value;
            if (e == null || e == "" || f == null || f == "" || g == null || g == "") {
                $(".form_error").show();
                $('html,body').animate({
                     scrollTop: $(".form_error").offset().top - 180 
                });


                var h = document.forms["register"]["compname"].value;
                var i = document.forms["register"]["compreg"].value;
                if (h == null || h == "" || i == null || i == "") {
                    $(".form_error").show();
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(".form_error").offset().top - 180 
                    });

                    return false;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [HTML/Javascript: Simple form validation on submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134733/html-javascript-simple-form-validation-on-submit) But to try and help, make sure you're actually executing the validation code using the `onSubmit` HTML attribute on the `<form>` tag itself.

Comment: you can call this method onsubmit form event and do e.preventDefault() and after that validate code and then document.form.submit(); or document.<form name>.submit();

Comment: @Innovation Thanks but I tried this and it doesn't make any difference the form still submits

Comment: Please cache `document.forms["register"]` instead of repeating yourself all those times…

Comment: provide your html code.

Answer (score 22):

In the form tag there is a field *onsubmit* to specify your validation function.
Something like that:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <!-- your inputs -->

</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use `event.preventDefault();` in your if statement when you check for errors.

I you are clicking a submit button, first check all the fields, if something fails in your validation, raise `event.preventDefault()`. With this, this will prevent the form to submit.

If there are no errors, the `preventDefault` will not be raised and the form will be submitted.

Extra information:
[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: thanks I tried adding that but still didn't prevent the form submiting