# Getting JavaScript validation to work with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
//send to database
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script>
    function validateForm() {
        var usernameentry = document.forms["registrationform"]["username2"].value;
        var passwordentry = document.forms["registrationform"]["password2"].value;
        var nameentry = document.forms["registrationform"]["password2"].value;

        var emailentry = document.forms["registrationform"]["email"].value;
        var atpos = emailentry.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = emailentry.lastIndexOf(".");



        if (usernameentry.length < 3  ||  username.length > 20){
            alert("Username must be inbetween 4 and 20 characters");
            return false;
        }

        else if (passwordentry.length < 3  ||  password.length > 20){
            alert("Password must be inbetween 4 and 20 characters");
            return false;
        }

        else if (nameentry.length < 3  ||  name.length > 45){
            alert("Name must be inbetween 4 and 45 characters");
            return false;
        }


        else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=emailentry.length  || emailentry.length > 154) {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>  
    <form name="registrationform" method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Username: <input type="text" name="username2"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password2"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    </form>
</body>
```

I want the contents of the if statement to run ONLY when the form has been validated with JavaScript, it runs regardless of whether the value returns is true or false.

I'm guessing what I need to do is similar to

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && onsubmit == true)
```

Obviously that's not right, but I don't know how to do it.

I know validating with php is a much more logical approach, but I need to demonstrate use of JavaScript.

Comment: What you've written should do exactly what you want. However, keep in mind that you can't rely on JavaScript actually running since it's possible to post to this page from a different location. But for a simple solution, this shoudl do it.

Comment: no need to add that `"onsubmit"` inside the PHP if, the onsubmit already ran when without errors on front when it returned `true` and continued the form submission.

Comment: The problem is that the contents of the if statement run regardless whether or not the value JavaScript returns is true or false.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. When the form is validated, it will be sent to login.php

You can see this question [HTML/Javascript: Simple form validation on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134733/html-javascript-simple-form-validation-on-submit)

Also, there are a lot of libraries which could help you 
http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml

Comment: I figured out it wasn't working properly due to the cache in Google Chrome. Thanks anyway